# Convert multiple CSV files to UTF-8 encoding using a script/Windows Command prompt

Tags: bash, encoding, utf-8, command

I am trying to create a script that converts the encoding of a collection of CSV files (10-20 files) in a directory into UTF-8 encoding. Currently, I am doing this manually by opening each individual file In NotePad+ and then switching the encoding to UTF-8, and then re-saving.

Are there any Windows commands or something else (I have Cygwin installed as well), that I could use to build a script to do this? Ideally, I would like the script to loop through every CSV file in the directory, and convert it into a UTF-8.

Thank you in advance for the help!!!

Comment: Convert from which encoding?

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying what to convert *from,* but assuming the input encoding is Windows-1252, try

```sh
for file in *.csv; do
    iconv -f cp-1252 <"$file" >"$file".tmp &&
    mv "$file.tmp" "$file"
done
```

This could leave some files unconverted (for example, if the input file contains bytes which are undefined in the source encoding) but will not overwrite the source file in this scenario. (Maybe disable the `mv` logic until you can see whether it works without errors.)

Comment: You tagged this [tag:bash] so I assume you are familiar enough with Bash to make sense of this. I'm guessing Cygwin includes `iconv` these days; if not, it should be easy to find and install.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that in PowerShell

```
Get-Content filename.csv | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 filename-utf8.csv
```

For your loop, you need to modularize your commands to where you can reference them and call them properly. In your case, you need to be calling "baseName" and appending ".csv" to it  After that, simply using the right variables in the right places in ForEach loop will make it work.

```
$a = Get-ChildItem
ForEach ($item in $a) {
  Get-Content $item.FullName | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 "$($item.Basename).csv.utf8"
}
```

Remember that before Powershell 6, Microsoft includes BOM ( Byte-Order Mark ). Three chars placed at the beginning of a file  in the conversion.

The conversion needs to create an additional file that later on you can use mv for replacing the original.